# Trigger.io and startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges possible?

Tags: ios, geolocation, background-process, trigger.io

I need to have the user's location updated while the app (built on Trigger.io's Forge) is in the background (for up to 30mins). Is there any way to implement startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges with Trigger.io for ios?

Comment: Curious if you ever moved forward with this, I need to accomplish same and am looking into building native module as @Connorhd suggested.

Comment: No haven't yet - it is still on the list of to-dos. Please let me know if you have any luck with it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be implemented as a native module, you can find the documentation for writing your own native modules here https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html